# jQuery selectable disable automatic unselect

Tags: jquery, selectable

I'm using jquerys [selectable widget](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#display-grid) with a grid-alike table. As one can see on the example, if you select box 1-4 and then select 5-6, the first selected values will be unselected automatically. Is there any way to reverse this effect? I want to be able to select multiple boxes to the left, then wait, then select multiple boxes on the right without having the previous selected values unselected. While we're at it, I only want to unselect them when I select already selected boxes.

I have tried using

```
unselecting: function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('ui-selected') == false) {
        return;
    }
}
```

and similar but with no luck.

Comment: Could be usefull with a working sample on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to see it in action what you have made until now.

Comment: Well, basically my code is not more complicated than the jQuery grid example. The only option I have so far is the filter where I only want to be able to select specific columns in the table.

Comment: Did you try hold ctrl-key down while selecting 5-6 - that should keep the selected 1-4 to stay - it does here. If thats not what you wanted - please tell me exact what you want again, or tell me where I failed to understand :)

Comment: Yes, I know that holding down CTRL will allow me to select additional values. However, I want to be able to select addtional values _without_ having to do so. :)